# Android based virtual companion using voice exchange

Tags: android, 3d, virtual

I am presently developing an Android app a Virtual companion using voice exchange. I have already made the voice receiver.The question is how to integrate a 3D model into Android.

Answer (score 0):

The Android approach for 3d is [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). It is a multi platform 2d and 3d standard, which is used in modern browsers as well as on iOS, too.

But you could skip real 3d technology by using plane image animation inside your app. You would generate 3d scenes on your desktop computer, render them and just use those rendered images or a created movie inside your mobile application.

Comment: i have already generated a 3D objects. thanks i will render it on Unity3D

Comment: I already rendered my 3D image but failed to do the animation on Unity3D.

Comment: If you want to avoid Unity3D problems, you can go do it as described in the answer's second paragraph. This will work with older phones as well.